# Creating two methods to treat arrays

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have two char-Arrays of length 5. Each one of them includes ( 'a','b','c' or is empty).

I need to make two methods:

**1) Method 1: public boolean friends(...)**

Array1 and array2 are friends if and only if you can change array1 into array2 by changing one character type ('a', 'b' or 'c') in the array (' ' can't be changed).

```
example('a'): aa_ab  and bb_bc are friends.
```

**2) Method 2: public boolean allies(...)**

Array1 and array2 are allies if and only if you can change array1 into array2 by adding one character type ('a', 'b' or 'c') in array1.

Anyone has an idea how I should proceed?

*Edit:*

I'm sorry if some people perceived my post as the urge for other people to do the homework for me.

That's not the case at all. I've been stuck on these couple of methods for more than two hours, so I'll try to explain my difficulties concerning the first one a bit more thoroughly:

1) First of all, I made this private method to change a character:

private void change(char x, char newCharacter) {

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

           if (array1[i] == 'x'){
               array1[i] = newCharacter;}
           }
    }
```

2) Next I thought about going into every case separately with if, but I would neen 12 if.

3) The first method has a form of a tree, so maybe there is another way to do things. I just can't seem to find that way(if it exists).

One idea of mine was to sort the array, and then only compare the order. Another to make an array of arrays and see if array2 was in it. But both didn't work out.

So I'll explain the sorting method which makes the most sense:

- if there is a space character in one the arrays but not in the other, it returns false.
- then count the order of occurence of each character
- if it's the same, it's true, if not then false.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code request.

Comment: Idea: try doing your homework on your own first. You learn nothing by dumping it on other people. Well, you learn something right now: that such requests do not fly well here ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it (we can vote to reopen your question if it you improve it enough).

Comment: OK, nice, a little bit of more improvement, and we'll open it for you.

Comment: I see you tried to improve your question. That is great! You can improve it farther by limiting it to only one problem instead of two separate ones (even if they can be similar they are not the same). Anyway I am not sure how to understand your question correctly. All I can give you is hint that we can treat characters as numbers. For instance we can write `char ch = 'a' + 1;` and get `'b'` because `'a'` can be treated as position of `a` character in Unicode Table (which is 97). Same way we can write `'b' - 'a'` and get `1`.

Comment: @Pshemo Nice trick there with the ASCII code values!

Comment: @Pshemo I am trying to reopen it, may others join me.

Comment: @GingerHead While current close reason may be not valid, IMO question is still not clear enough to fit SO which is why I will wait for now with my reopening vote.

Comment: @Pshemo yep clearly, I agree